# How to obtain the form of a particular solution of an ODE if we have a trigonometric function as f(x)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have $y'' -3y' + 2y = sin(4x)$

There is no problem to obtain $y_h$. However, I do not understand properly how to obtain the form of the particular solution of this ODE. As I know, if we had, for instance, $... = 3x^2$, we would have $y_p = Ax^2$. But for this particular case, $... = sin(4x)$, I do not know how to proceed, since my hand book says the form should be $y_p = Asin(4x) + Bcos(4x)$.

I think the problem here is that I am not proceeding correctly to obtain the form of particular solutions in general, so I would really appreciate if you can clarify how to obtain that form for any case, so then we will be able to solve this and any other kind of particular solution.

Thank you very much.

Comment: See the nice table here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx and Example 6.

Comment: To be exact the right attempt for $3x^2$ would be $y_p=Ax^2+Bx+C$. But I can only recommend the given link hence I have learned for myself from this side.

Comment: $\sin(4x) = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{i4x}-e^{-i4x})$ and the general solution to a DE  linear with constant coefficients always involves $e^{\lambda x }$...

Comment: Thank you all. Your notes and that website were very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must ask yourself "what function can give a sine when you form a linear combination of its derivatives up to second order" ?

If you have in mind the successive derivatives of the sine, you know that they are sines and cosines, and similarly for the cosine function.

As $A\sin(4x)$ alone doesn't work, we are lead to try a mixture like $A\sin(4x)+B\cos(4x)$, which does work.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to keep this hint in mind for further exercises.

Comment: @IgnacioValdésZamudio: the reasoning also works when the RHS is a polynomial of degree $d$: the solution must be another polynomial of degree $d$ because a linear combination of a polynomial and its derivatives is a polynomial of the same degree.

Comment: I see the point. With this last comment everything made sense. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If $y_p = A\sin(4x) + B\cos(4x)$ then

$$y_p'=4A\cos(4x)-4B\sin(4x)$$ and

$$y_p''=-16A\sin(4x)-16B\cos(4x).$$ So

$$y_p''-3y_p'+2y_p=\sin(4x)$$ if and only if $$(-16A+12B+2A)\sin (4x)+(-16B-12A+2B)\cos (4x)=\sin (4x).$$

Solve the system

\begin{cases}-16A+12B+2A=1\\ -16B-12A+2B=0\end{cases} and you are done.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, my problem was how to reach to "y_p = Asin(4x) + Bcos(4x). Could you explain it, please?

Comment: See http://www.efunda.com/math/ode/linearode_undeterminedcoeff.cfm for a table to find particular solutions in several cases.

Comment: Thank you ver much.